# Can we connect iPhone to XBox via Bluetooth?

Tags: iphone, ios4, bluetooth, xbox360

I guess the question says it all.

Can we connect iPhone to XBox via Bluetooth?

If we can, can we programmatically access Bluetooth using iPhone SDK to send and receive data to XBox?

Answer (score 0):

No - we cannot.
iPhones can only connect over bluetooth with approved accessories, which needs the accessory to be MFi compliant, Xbox is not.